# (KAFKA Oracle DEBEZIUM) Unable to connect: Failed to resolve Oracle database version

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, debezium

i have setup kafka debezium on UBUNTU server and created sql connector and that works perfectly fine. then i created oracle connector and i m getting this error "Unable to connect: Failed to resolve Oracle database version"
i have followed strictly the documentation from debezium here.
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/oracle.html
[debezium oracle kafka documentaion](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/oracle.html)

i have doubt over the config about following attributes.

```
    "database.server.name" Is this same as host name ????
    "database.hostname" : server host name where oracle db is running (myserver.domain.com)
    "database.user" : user with all the permission required (except FLASHBACK ANY TABLE)
    "database.out.server.name": (IS THIS REQUUIRED????)
```

Answer (score 0):

The connector configuration options you're asking about are described [here](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/oracle.html#oracle-connector-properties).  That said, I'll cover them below for completeness.

`database.server.name`
This acts as a logical or unique name for the specific Oracle database that is being captured.  If you deploy multiple connectors, each connector should have a unique  name since this is used as a prefix for all Kafka topic names created or associated with this connector deployment.  Since this is used as part of the Kafka topic names, Kafka topic name restrictions apply, meaning this should only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores only.

`database.hostname`
This should contain the IP address or the hostname from where the Oracle database can be reached.

`database.user`
This is the name of the user that the connector will use to connect and interact with the Oracle.  In the documentation, this would be the user that you created by following [these steps](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/oracle.html#_creating_users_for_the_connector).

`database.out.server.name`
This setting is only applicable if you intend to use the Oracle XStream adapter, which requires setting the `database.connection.adapter=xstream` in your connector configuration.  If you aren't specifying this alternative adapter, the connector will use the native Oracle LogMiner database tool and this setting can safely be omitted.